# Solana Wallet Adaptor autoconnecting after reload/change page

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I'm currently creating a react+typescript website with Solana Wallet Adapter. I have routes setup and I want to keep the wallet connected when I go between pages or when I'm reloading the page. I know I can use the autoconnect but I want to keep the connection on and the publickey to be in localstate. Do you know if this is possible and how?

Comment: you might get better engagement by supplying code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Your Routes should be inside the wallet context, so first write the Wallet component:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import {
    WalletModalProvider,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
    WalletMultiButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';

// Default styles that can be overridden by your app
require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

export function Wallet({ children }: any) {
    // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

    // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
        ],
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        [network]
    );

    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    <WalletMultiButton />
                    <WalletDisconnectButton />
                    { /* Your app's components go here, nested within the context providers. */}
                    {children}
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};
```

And then write the Routes inside the Wallet component:

```
import './App.css';
import { Wallet } from './components/Wallet';
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  HashRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from './pages/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Wallet>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </Wallet>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```